# Terminal displays wrong php version (Snow Leopard)

Tags: php, macos, terminal, osx-snow-leopard

Need to downgrade php to 5.2.x, so I followed this tutorial:
http://andreys.info/blog/2010-03-25/compile-php-5-2-on-osx-10-6-snow-leopard#comment-631

I'm on snow leopard 10.6.4, with xcode installed.

So I compiled php5.2.x and completed the tutorial. phpinfo() loaded within the browser at htp://localhost says 5.2.x, Great!! But, Terminal command "php --version" says 5.3.x ??

While compiling/installing php5.2.x, the new module file replaced the php5.3.x module here:
/usr/libexec/apache2/libphp5.so

1. So where is Terminal getting 5.3.x from?
2. Do I have two php versions being loaded?
3. Should I even care?

Comment: My guess is that you've got both versions installed, and calling `php` is running the executable for 5.3.x.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Check using `which php`. This should tell you which is being used.
2. Yes, looks like you have two installed at different locations.
3. Yes, mind what's being used where. Having multiple versions is absolutely valid (at least on a development or testing system) but you always should be aware of the versions being used.

Comment: Ok running 'which php' in terminal gives: /usr/bin/php. The php that i compiled, 5.2.x, seems to be here: /usr/local/php5/bin. How come when loading php from localhost in browser uses 5.2.x but terminal php command uses 5.3.x? I just want to have one running at a time. What to do?

Comment: The version in the browser is absolutely independent. Check your server configuration ... like /etc/apache/httpd.conf or such which most likely loads a /usr/local/php5/lib/libphp5.so or such.

Comment: LoadModule php5_module        libexec/apache2/libphp5.so. However, this file libphp5.so is the compiled file for 5.2.x! It's no longer the 5.3.x version that came with osx. So why it Terminal showing 5.3.x? I'm spending too much time on this and really don't want to resort to MAMP...Thanks for your help btw

Comment: You have one file libexec/apache2/libphp5.so containing one version. You also have /usr/bin/php, which is a different file containing a different version. And you have /usr/local/php5/bin/php which is yet another file. Each of these files contains the complete PHP. One time with an interface for talking to apache, the other ones for talking to the command line.

Comment: This makes sense. I did this in terminal: 
$ /usr/local/php5/bin/php --version
...This shows the correct php install and version.

Comment: "which php" does not tell the version; it only tells the path. The correct command is "php -v"

Comment: @user908998 For what I can tell the poster mentioned he knows the version but asked "So where is Terminal getting 5.3.x from?" so `which` is the way to go.

Comment: so how to force terminal to use the other version? I didnt get how you did it guys

Answer (score 15):

For a more direct solution to the problem:

1. Rename the OLD version of PHP

   `sudo mv /usr/bin/php /usr/bin/php5424`
2. Create a Symbolic link for your new version of php so it can live in /usr/bin

   `sudo ln -s /usr/local/php5/bin/php /usr/bin/php`

Comment: Worked for me as well, if you have a different folder name instead of php5 you will encounter this error: `dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/php5/lib/libtidy-0.99.0.dylib`