# How to update PHP CLI OSX?

Tags: php, macos, apache, osx-lion

I just updated to php 5.4 using http://php-osx.liip.ch/ on osx lion.

when i type:

```
php -v
```

i still see:

```
PHP 5.3.15 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Jul 31 2012 14:49:18) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2012 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies
```

But phpinfo() shows 5.4.

How do i update this?

Comment: if you run `which php` you'll find you are pointing at a different php executable (if it points at `/usr/local/bin` - check if that's a symlink - and where it's pointing)

Comment: I see. It is pointing at `/usr/bin/php` So how can I repoint to the correct executable?

Comment: Look at this forum, you will find the answer.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3973271/terminal-displys-wrong-php-version-snow-leopard

Comment: "This package installs the (usually) latest PHP 5.3.x/5.4.x on OS X 10.6 (aka Snow Leopard), OS X 10.7 (aka Lion) and OS X 10.8 (aka Mountain Lion) in /usr/local/php5" - so delete the symlink and point it at `/usr/local/php5/bin/php` (do not blindly do this, check that's the right path) - or add `/usr/local/php5/bin`to your PATH.

Comment: Added `/usr/local/php5/bin` to my path. Worked like a charm. Thank you!

Answer (score 17):

Just Export installed PHP path  ,type this on Terminal

```
export PATH=/usr/local/php5/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me for version 7. Still the PHP-CLI version is 5.6. Can you please help me on this?

Answer (score 3):

I checked that `/usr/local/php5/bin/php` existed. It did, so I added `/usr/local/php5/bin` to my PATH.

Thank you @AD7six

Comment: I didn't get what you mean if /usr/local/php5/bin/php exists already means /usr/local/php5/bin/ also exist without adding it?

Answer (score 1):

The answer shared by both Chutipong Roobklom and user1168427 helped, if you want to update to the latest php cli which is 7.2.7 (most current and stable release as of 2018 when this post was created originally so check the latest php version, methods for switching versions may vary) then just use this instead of the php5 command. `export PATH=/usr/local/php7/bin:$PATH` then type `php -v` and you should have something that reads like this(on MACOSX by the way):

`PHP 7.2.7 (cli) (built: Jun 22 2018 06:27:50) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.2.7, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies`

so you shouldn't be getting any errors. Hope this helps and for Kamel, that is how it is installed. You're kind of 'exposing' it in a way for your machine to now recognize which php version you are using.